# Way of working out the percentage of coloured cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I believe this may be a fairly simple question to the Excel gurus out there but is there an easy way to just simply calculate and show the percentage of which cells are green, what percentage are yellow and what percentage are red?

Hopefully a simple answer to a simple question! Thank you.

Comment: You want to set the cell color according to the cell percent value?

Comment: I just want to highlight a set of cells and do something that shows me the percentage of each color within the selection. Or something to that effect.

Comment: There is a well-known VBA UDF called **CountColor**; google it; I'm assuming that if you can count the colors, you can calculate a percentage.